# Как работает ListAdapter?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Раньше я использовал RecyclerView и ViewHolder для создания списков, но мне посоветовали для динамичных списков использовать `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`. Но в интернете я нашел мало информации и то на kotlin, а я знаю Java. Объясните пожалуйста как он работает.

Comment: То же самое, только с встроенной коллекцией и механизмом асинхронного обновления через `DiffUtil`. В документации вроде всё предельно ясно: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter